# CCParallaxNode moves on and convertToWorldSpace give wrong values cocos2d iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have used the code below for collision detection. but as CCParallaxNode moves on in infinite scrolling. my positions goes wrong.
i have tries every possible solution till yet. but everything gives me wrong values in parallax.

```
for (CCSprite *sp in PathsArray) {
        if (sp.tag==500) {
            CGPoint sprect=[self convertToWorldSpace:sp.position];
            CGRect pillerRect=CGRectMake(sprect.x, sprect.y, sp.boundingBox.size.width, sp.boundingBox.size.height);
            CGRect heroRect=CGRectMake(charcterObject.boundingBox.origin.x, charcterObject.boundingBox.origin.y, charcterObject.sp4.boundingBox.size.width, charcterObject.sp4.boundingBox.size.height);

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(heroRect, pillerRect)) {
                [self stopJumping];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the sprites children of self in the above code ?

Comment: yes CCParallaxNode and Hero are children of self.
and pillar are children of ParallaxNode

Comment: that is probably your problem, you should obtain worldPosition from sp's parent.

Comment: yes, you are right.please send this thing in answer. i will mark it correct for future help. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, both rectangles have to be in the same coordinate system. You should probably get position for *sp as

```
CGPoint sprect=[sp.parent convertToWorldSpace:sp.position];
```

because sp.position is in the parent's coordinates system.